Python Pandas data frame column split based on previous unique columns combination
I have a data frame like below:
TAG TAG_NAME    METRIC    METRIC_NAME CAPTURE_DATE      MB
DB  PRO     SPACE           A       2024-03-01      3
DB  PRO     SPACE       B       2024-03-01      4
DB  PRO     SPACE       C       2024-03-01      5
DB  PRO     SPACE           D       2024-03-01      6
DB  PRO     SPACE       E       2024-03-01      7
DB  PRO     SPACE           A       2024-03-01      8
DB  PRO     SPACE       B       2024-03-01      9   
DB  PRO     SPACE       C       2024-03-01      10
DB  PRO     SPACE           D       2024-03-01      11
DB  PRO     SPACE       E       2024-03-01      12

I want to split column MB based on the unique combination of columns (TAG, TAG_NAME, METRICS, CAPTURE_DATE).
And the output should look like below:
TAG TAG_NAME    METRIC    METRIC_NAME CAPTURE_DATE      MB_Firt    MB_Second
DB  PRO     SPACE           A       2024-03-01      3       8
DB  PRO     SPACE       B       2024-03-01      4       9
DB  PRO     SPACE       C       2024-03-01      5       10
DB  PRO     SPACE           D       2024-03-01      6       11
DB  PRO     SPACE       E       2024-03-01      7       12

I am new to pandas/Python. Your help will be highly appreciated.
I tried with pivot and melt, no help

This is a pivot, see #10 in the duplicate

Use the groupby()
import pandas as pd

# Creating the initial data frame to debug
data = {
    'TAG': ['DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'],
    'TAG_NAME': ['PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'PRO'],
    'METRIC': ['SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE', 'SPACE'],
    'METRIC_NAME': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'CAPTURE_DATE': ['2024-03-01'] * 10,
    'MB': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by the columns and aggregate 'MB' values ionto a list in that column
grouped = df.groupby(['TAG', 'TAG_NAME', 'METRIC', 'METRIC_NAME', 'CAPTURE_DATE'])['MB'].apply(list).reset_index()

# Split 'MB' into the separate columns
grouped[['MB_First', 'MB_Second']] = pd.DataFrame(grouped['MB'].tolist(), index=grouped.index)

# then drop the original 'MB' column
grouped = grouped.drop(columns=['MB'])

To do without .tolist()
# Assign an index to differentiateoccurrences
df['index'] = df.groupby(['TAG', 'TAG_NAME', 'METRIC', 'METRIC_NAME', 'CAPTURE_DATE']).cumcount() + 1

# Then pivot the table
pivot_df = df.pivot(index=['TAG', 'TAG_NAME', 'METRIC', 'METRIC_NAME', 'CAPTURE_DATE'], columns='index', values='MB')

#rRename the columns to what you would like
pivot_df.columns = ['MB_First', 'MB_Second']

# Reset index to flatten the DataFrame
pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()


Would it be possible to do this without converting dataframes to lists? It feels like we would lose all the performance of pandas by converting them to lists. Or is it equally performant?

you're not converting the dataframe to a list, just the values that belong to the groupby in the 'MB' column. But sure it can be done with making lists

I see, so only two element lists will be created, right? (that should be no problem)

yes - put a print(grouped) right after grouped = df.groupby(['TAG', 'TAG_NAME', 'METRIC', 'METRIC_NAME', 'CAPTURE_DATE'])['MB'].apply(list).reset_index(), and you can see how its working

If I understand correctly, you are looking for group_by and reset_index. I don't know of a better solution, but please let me know if you find one.
>>> grouped = df.groupby(['TAG', 'TAG_NAME', 'METRIC', 'CAPTURE_DATE','METRIC_NAME'])
>>> updated_df = grouped.apply(lambda gr: (gr.reset_index()['MB'][0], gr.reset_index()['MB'][1]),include_groups=False).reset_index()
>>> updated_df['MB_First'] = updated_df[0].apply(lambda x:x[0])
>>> updated_df['MB_Second'] = updated_df[0].apply(lambda x:x[1])
>>> print(updated_df)
  TAG TAG_NAME METRIC CAPTURE_DATE METRIC_NAME MB_First  MB_Second
0  DB      PRO  SPACE   2024-03-01           A        3          8
1  DB      PRO  SPACE   2024-03-01           B        4          9
2  DB      PRO  SPACE   2024-03-01           C        5         10
3  DB      PRO  SPACE   2024-03-01           D        6         11
4  DB      PRO  SPACE   2024-03-01           E        7         12

Is this what you were looking for?
